# What/where is TAdapterJSONValue?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to follow the example [Use TRESTDataSetAdapter with arbitrary JSON](https://community.embarcadero.com/pt/blogs/entry/use-trestdatasetadapter-with-arbitrary-json).

It uses a `TAdapterJSONValue` type that I cannot get to compile.

- Somebody else has been trying the same here, but [his/her question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349886/how-do-i-get-a-dynamic-tclientdataset-based-on-trestresponsedatasetadapter-to) does not show units.
- I've tried including lots of `REST.xxx` units but no luck
- I've searched the Delphi sources and the `TAdapterJSONValue` type definition is in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\data\ems\rsconsole\RSConsole.Types.pas`, but the IDE does not recognize `RSConsole` or `RSConsole.Types` in the uses clause
- Since this references 'EMS', I tried several `EMS.xxx` units without luck
- There's nothing about `TAdapterJSONValue` in `c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Samples\`
- The example 'can be downloaded from here' points to Google Drive, where you have to do a request, and <strike>who knows if/when that gets honored...</strike> nobody has replied to that request after a week.

Note that the example was for Delphi 10.2, I'm using 11.3. It's a VCL app, not FMX.

Comment: Might it be this? A wild guess after googling. https://github.com/JesusMayuri7/agcc_movil/blob/master/uAdapterJson.pas

Comment: @MatthiasB That is exactly the code in c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\data\ems\rsconsole\RSConsole.Types.pas ;-) Of course I can copy it out, but I'd rather find the correct unit name.

Comment: Ah ...  Maybe it's a Delphi bug - not fully set up default search paths? You could work around it by adding $(BDS)\source\data\ems\rsconsole to the Browsing path under Tool > Options > Language > Delphi > Library. I see that it contains several $(BDS)\source\data\xxxxx paths, but not this concrete one.